# What is the projector decomposition of a symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Hi I am studying linear algebra and I bumped into projector decomposition of symmetric matrices and I just don’t know what it is can anyone of you help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is a symmetric matrix over a real space or a Hermitian matrix over a complex space, then
$$
                       Ax = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\lambda_n P_nx
$$
where $\{ \lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_N \}$ are the distinct eigenvalues of $A$, and where $P_n$ is the orthogonal projection onto the eigenspace $\mathcal{ker}(A-\lambda_n I)$. For example, if $\{ e_{n,1},e_{n,2},\cdots,e_{n,k_n} \}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mbox{ker}(A-\lambda_n I)$, then the orthogona projection $P_n$ may be written as
$$
        P_nx = \sum_{j=1}^{k_n}\langle x,e_{n,j}\rangle e_{n,j}
$$

These projections satisfy:
$$
     P_n^2 = P_n, \\ P_n^*= P_n\; (\mbox{or } P_n^{T}=P_n \mbox{ for real spaces}) \\
      P_nP_m = 0  \mbox{ for } n\ne m \\
       AP_n = \lambda_n P_n \\
          \sum_{n=1}^{N} P_n = I,\\
        A = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\lambda_n P_n.
$$